# Is it possible to play OpenTTD with a Magic Trackpad?

Tags: magic-trackpad

Is it possible to play OpenTTD with a Magic Trackpad?

The game uses a rigth-click and move mouse while pressed to move around map, and it is almost only way to move around. It is possible to do this movement with the Magic Trackpad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenTTD's advanced settings, you can configure `Command-Click` to behave as right click. Then you can hold `Command` to move.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but will this allow me to do moveing around the map (move map to up/down/left/right)? Will this work on Windows OS?

Comment: @osgx Yes, that's exactly what it does. It allows you to `Cmd-Click-and-drag` instead of `Right-click-and-drag`. I don't know whether that option is present on Windows. I assumed you were on OS X since Windows Explorer e.g. uses the same gesture. There [a topic on Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30624/right-click-drag-with-magic-trackpad) about it that might help you.

Comment: This method requires a keyboard and is bit uncomfortable. There is no such option in latest beta.

Comment: But, there is an option "Left-click scrolling" which solves my problem. And the interectin fact is that action from click+drag from left button and right button differs. Both buttons allows me to scroll map with this option.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently you can hold the control button while clicking, or you can set your system for two fingered clicks equaling  right-clicking. The former seems to be a more sensible option in your scenario.

Comment: just checked. Ctrl-click is not equal a right click on windows. Clicking with 2 fingers is clicking, but if I ll move both finger after that - is will be scrolling. Again, I need a "move while left button is pressed"